# About forcing a checkmate

Tags: checkmate, problems, forced-move

Could a player sacrifice 3 of his pieces , the opponent's King being forced to take each piece in a sequence of moves where the opponent's King lands on a space where it is promptly checkmated? A kind of 3-move forced checkmate. Could this be done with 4 moves?

Comment: Could a similar 3-move forcing of the opponents King be done to force a stalemate position?

Comment: Are you allowing a pawn to count as a "piece" here?  If yes then one can surely go well beyond 4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

White to play and mate in 4, while forcing the black king to capture on each move:

```
[fen "1r2qrnk/3R1bRp/pp2nBpp/p3P3/4B3/5PPQ/PPP3N1/1K6 w - - 0 1"]
```

Solution:

> 1.Rxh7 Kxh7  
>  2.Bxg6 Kxg6  
>  3.Qf5 Kxf5  
>  4.Nh4#

Answer (score 0):

On a similar note, here is a [pretty problem](https://www.yacpdb.org/#327955) forces Black to take all eight pieces and two pawns in order to give checkmate with the last pawn!

```
[Title "Julio César Infantozzi, Mate In 16 Moves"]
[FEN "R1n2N2/4pk1B/2Q1r2B/2K2b2/Rr1n2P1/1q1P1PP1/4N2b/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Qe8+ Kxe8 2. Rxc8+ Kf7 3. Bg8+ Kxg8 4. Ng6+ Kh7 5. Rh8+ Kxg6 6. Nf4+ Kf6 7. Rf8+ Ke5 8. Bg7+ Rf6 9. Bxf6+ exf6 10. Re8+ Ne6+ 11. Rxe6+ Qxe6 12. Ng6+ Bxg6  13. f4+ Rxf4 14. gxf4+ Bxf4 15. Re4+ Bxe4 16. d4
```

Additionally, I found another problem in a Dutch [article by Tim Krabbe](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/admag/woest.htm) where White gives away four queens, two rooks, and two knights to also give mate with the last pawn. The most heaviest bag of material sacrificed in a chess problem ever!

```
[Title "Mate in 13 Moves, Gerhad Josten, Tim Krabbe “ONSTERFELIJKE WOESTHEID”, 2000"]
[FEN "1q4r1/1bp2pQ1/3Q4/1Kp1pr2/1n1pkp1p/RQ1RN3/nbnP4/QN6 w - - 0 1"]

1. Kc4 cxd6 2. Nc3+ Nxc3 3. Qh1+ f3 4. Qxh4+ Rf4 5. Qhh7+ f5 6. Qxb7+ Qxb7 7.  Qxb7+ d5+ 8. Qxd5+ Ncxd5 9. Nxd5 Nxd5 10. Re3+ Ncxe3+ 11. Qxe3+ Nxe3+ 12. Rxe3+  dxe3 13. d3#
```